# Is there a way to read user's atlassian confluence data within my own web app?

Tags: python, single-sign-on, jira, confluence, confluence-rest-api

All my users in my web app are signed in using Microsoft Azure AD SSO, and all of the users have access to Atlassian Confluence with the same account. I want to read all the Confluence content that is available to the user to automate some process.

My understanding is we can use API tokens to access one's content, but this is not feasible as I could not get everyone's API tokens in place?

Could you suggest me some way to implement this?